# How can I enable a lock in Python to control which threads are able to write to my log file and my screen?

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, locking, logfile

Essentially I have three threads, and the second one and it logs information. I need to create a lock to control which threads are able to write to the log file and the screen. So because the second thread is the only one writing to the log file, it should be the only one with access to the log file.

How can I implement a lock to control which threads can write to the logfile?

Comment: Can you post some sample code of what you're doing?

Comment: Locks are for preventing multiple threads from, say, writing to the same file at the same time. They are not there to completely lock out some threads. If only one thread is expected to write to the log file, you shouldn't need any locks or other measures at all.

Comment: Threads only do what your program tells them to do. You say "...the second thread is the only one writing to the log file." OK. So, what's the problem? No other threads will write to the log file if you don't write any code that _makes_ them write to the log file. Maybe what you want is to stick an _[assertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development))_ into a logging function that will cause a test to fail if somebody accidentally changes your code to call the function from a thread that should not call it.